# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.

Tags: java, mysql

(the Stored Procedure runs perfectly in MySQL Workbench and also retrieves the Rows)

Here is My Code :

```
    ConnectionManager cm = new ConnectionManager();
    java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = null;

    try
    {
             connect = cm.getConnection();
             connect.createStatement();
             String SQL = "{call getReportDetails ('"+ emailId +"','"+password+"')}";
             cstmt = connect.prepareCall(SQL);
             rs = cstmt.executeQuery(SQL);              
             int i = 0;
             while(rs.next())
             {
                 String element1 = rs.getString("description");
                 // -- some code --
             }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
  {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: see your stored procedure. are you trying to get the password for given emailID?

Comment: No Brother. just they are parameters which are sent to stored Procedure and there is no any out parameter from Stored Procedure. there is No any Problem with SP it works Properly in MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the line with `createStatement`.
And (the error) do not use SQL as parameter of executeQuery.

(The overloaded version with an sql parameter is for the immediate, non-prepared statement version.)

Further close statement and result set; try-with-resources will do nice here.

```
try (CallableStatement cstmt =
        connect.prepareCall"{call getReportDetails (?, ?)}")) {
    cstmt.setString(1, emailId);
    cstmt.setString(2, password);
    try (ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery()) {              
         int i = 0;
         while (rs.next())
         {
             String element1 = rs.getString("description");
             // -- some code --
         }
     }
}
```

---

In the general case for stored functions you might need to specify the result yourself:

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
rs.getString(2);
```

But here you have a ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
try {
     cs = connectionObject.prepareCall("{call getReportDetails (?, ?)}");
     cs.setString(1, emailId);
     cs.setString(2, password);
     cs.execute();
     ResultSet rs = cs.getResultSet();
          while (rs.next()) {
             System.out.println(rs.getString("columnLabel"));
           }
    }
catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
finally{
//close statements
}
```